# Algorithm to find optimised resource allocation

Tags: algorithm

I am doing a project named 'Resource Gathering and Project Allocation'. In the project, the admin has to first register the project. After registering he divides the project into various modules. Once the work division is completed, he needs to gather the resources for the project. Resources means developers, testers, analysts etc. Later when the resources are obtained, the work is assigned to them.So for the same, I need an algorithm which will give an optimised allocation of work to the employees considering inputs like:-type of project, skills needed, budget estimated etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no effort is displayed

Comment: story of my life. Let me know when you are done

Comment: An algorithm can only be devised if the problem is formalized more rigurously.

Comment: *I am doing a project*  hmm, seems like we're doing the heavy lifting here.  As a project manager you'll go far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) to do this. As an example - find a way to encode resource allocation by combinations in sequence of bits. After that you should create a fitness function to evaluate efficiency of each generated sequence of bits in a meaning of resource allocation represented by this combination of bits.

You can find practical example of the implementation of this approach to figure out of ANN structure and weights for particular recognition tasks [here](http://3dboom.com.ua/news.php?news_id=33).